# Gnuradio leaving directory error

Tags: software-installation

I'm installing gnuradio 3.4.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - 64bit.
After "./configure". i get:

```
    *********************************************************************
The following components were skipped either because you asked not
to build them or they didn't pass configuration checks:

usrp2-firmware

These components will not be built.


*********************************************************************
The following GNU Radio components have been successfully configured:

config
gruel
volk
gnuradio-core
usrp
usrp2
gr-usrp
gr-usrp2
gr-msdd6000
gr-audio
gr-atsc
gr-cvsd-vocoder
gr-gpio
gr-gsm-fr-vocoder
gr-noaa
gr-pager
gr-radar-mono
gr-radio-astronomy
gr-trellis
gr-video-sdl
gr-wxgui
gr-qtgui
gr-sounder
gr-utils
gnuradio-examples
grc
docs

You my now run the make command to build these components.

*********************************************************************
The following components were skipped either because you asked not
to build them or they didn't pass configuration checks:

gcell
gr-gcell
gr-comedi
gr-uhd
gr-shd

These components will not be built.

Configured GNU Radio release 3.4.2 for build.
```

After running "make", I'm getting this in the end:

```
linux-gnu/crtn.o  -pthread -pthread   -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,libgnuradio-qtgui-3.4.2.so.0 -o .libs/libgnuradio-qtgui-3.4.2.so.0.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -laudio
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXi
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[5]: *** [libgnuradio-qtgui.la] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/akula/OpenBts/gnuradio-3.4.2/gr-qtgui/lib'
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/akula/OpenBts/gnuradio-3.4.2/gr-qtgui/lib'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/akula/OpenBts/gnuradio-3.4.2/gr-qtgui'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/akula/OpenBts/gnuradio-3.4.2/gr-qtgui'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/akula/OpenBts/gnuradio-3.4.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I try to install couple more versions but with same result. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: gnu radio is in the repositories. You should install it with `sudo apt-get install gnuradio` . Why are you installing from source ? To build from source, use the build script - http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/InstallingGRFromSource

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I agree but it seems that there's no Gnuradio package for 12.04 (http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnuradio&searchon=names)

Comment: OIC, use the script ;)

Comment: See also http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/UbuntuInstall

Comment: Because 'sudo apt-get install gnuradio' will install newest version and that one does not support usrp1

Comment: I try all advices, still no results.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need some development packages to compile Gnuradio from source. From the error you posted I would install the following packages, open a Terminal a type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev libxi-dev
```

You'll probably have to get several other -dev packages to compile it though.

Take a look at the [source package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/saucy/gnuradio), they're all all listed as **build-depends**.

Comment: I did what you said and got same result. I see page with packages but is there any way to install them all at once? One by one would take years.

Comment: Bodhi.zazen gave you the [solution](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/InstallingGRFromSource#Using-the-build-gnuradio-script).

Comment: For 12.04, the apt-get command is [here](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/UbuntuInstall#Precise-Pangolin-1204)

Comment: Guys, in this link I can find only how to install gnuradio 3.6 or 3.7. If you can tell me how to install 3.5 or 3.4, you coud save my day. Sorry for killing you with questions but I am new in Linux... Thanks

Comment: Edit: I need gnuradio 3.3 or 3.4